# How to apply a skybox ARTexture3D, in Android KudanAR SDK?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, kudan

I am working with the Android KudanSDK and cannot get an environment cube/ skybox working. The model appears black. Could anyone give me a hint? That would be nice.

I am not sure, if in the constructor of ARTexture3D the path to the png files (one for each cube side) shall be passed.
What I have done so far:

```
    String s = "wave.png";      
    ARTexture3D environmentTex = new ARTexture3D(s,s,s,s,s,s);
    ARLightMaterial lightMaterial = new ARLightMaterial();
    lightMaterial.setDiffuse(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    lightMaterial.setAmbient(1f, 1f, 1f);
    lightMaterial.setSpecular(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    lightMaterial.setTexture(shoeTexture);
    lightMaterial.setCubeTexture(environmentTex);
    lightMaterial.setReflectivity(1f);
    List<ARMeshNode> allNodes =  modelNodeArray[0].getMeshNodes();
    for(ARMeshNode meshNode : allNodes){
        meshNode.setMaterial(lightMaterial);
    }
```

Somewhere in Kudan's iOS Wiki, there is also mentioned that a Light object (for example ARDirectionalLight) shall be added to the scene, too. But, for Android I cannot find this class.

Any idea is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using the constructor of ARTexture3D, the different strings are paths to UIImage images. The order is: back, front, up, down, right, left. As for the light class, try to use "ARLight" to create a light node.

Comment: Thanks @DisturbedNeo for your reply. I must still miss something. When creating an ARLight object, Android Studio gives me an error. Obviously, the class cannot be found. Please, see the screenshot. Do I have to add further libraries? As you may see from the pic, kudanar.jar and libKudan.so are already there.  Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0j5nl0mdw6qzfr/kudanARLight.png?dl=0

Comment: Hello @DisturbedNeo , Is the class ARLight missing in Android? I cannot find it in the API docs. And Android Studio gives an error , when creating an ARLight object. Please, see the screenshot in the above comment.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo : Thank you! ARMeshNode.setLightDirection() works fine.